# Android (Java) App update http to HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, rss, httpurlconnection

I am currently using my Android (Java) app on API 27. At the moment I am still using the HTTP method in legacy mode, but I want to switch to HTTPURLConnection in order to be able to update to API 28.

To start with HTTPURLConnection I have to add these two things:

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

Does anyone have a tip?

```
package de.andreas_rothhardt.rssbywapphosting;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public class RSSReader implements java.io.Closeable {

private final HttpClient httpclient;


private final RSSParserSPI parser;

public RSSReader(HttpClient httpclient, RSSParserSPI parser) {
this.httpclient = httpclient;
this.parser = parser;
}

public RSSReader(HttpClient httpclient, RSSConfig config) {
this(httpclient, new RSSParser(config));
}

public RSSReader(RSSConfig config) {
this(new DefaultHttpClient(), new RSSParser(config));
}

public RSSReader() {
this(new DefaultHttpClient(), new RSSParser(new RSSConfig()));
}


public RSSFeed load(String uri) throws RSSReaderException {
final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

InputStream feedStream = null;
try {

  final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);


  final StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
  if (status.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    throw new RSSReaderException(status.getStatusCode(),
        status.getReasonPhrase());
  }

  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  feedStream = entity.getContent();

  RSSFeed feed = parser.parse(feedStream);

  if (feed.getLink() == null) {
    feed.setLink(android.net.Uri.parse(uri));
  }

  return feed;
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  throw new RSSFault(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RSSFault(e);
} finally {
  Resources.closeQuietly(feedStream);
}
}


public void close() {
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

}
```

Comment: HttpUrlConnection is very basic for network calling why dont you move to okhttp or some other networking library like Retrofit?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. How do I include okhttp in my code?

Comment: Here is the complete guide for using okhttp library https://square.github.io/okhttp/ and you can follow any tutorial on google that shows the usage of okhttp.

Comment: Is there an easier way to convert this code to work for API 28?

Comment: This work for me in the Manifest: <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"</uses-library>